# Objective-C Globally Accessible Method

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In the Master-Detail Xcode template, where do I define a function such that it is globally accessible (by all UIViewControllers and their subclasses)?

Comment: this questions is so vague, that it could refer to half a dozen things.

Comment: What do you mean? I want to define a method, a block of code, which can be accessed by any UIViewController in my app.

Comment: So u mean an instance of an method (singleton)? or are you talking of an class, that you wil instanciate and call the objects method? you could be asking for delegation. Maybe you want global C functions. Anyway — you should make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some code that doesn't care what class of object calls it, it could probably be encapsulated into a function or subroutine instead of a method.

A method is a special type of function or subroutine that knows about an object and its class.  A function or subroutine is like a global method that doesn't.

Added:
Objective C is a superset of the C programming language.  So C functions and subroutines are the same in both languages.  You can write one in a (or any) .c or .m file, and declare it in a .h file to be included wherever you want it used.  Pass it parameters as needed and get a return value from functions, just like methods (except for being unrelated to any inherent class of object).

Added #2: But since you want your method to know about some NSStreams, then it should probably be a method of some Model class (MVC paradigm) containing those streams, and not truly global.  Pass this Model object to any view controllers or other classes that need to access it.

Comment: What is the difference between a method and a function?

Comment: "In object-oriented programming, a method is a subroutine (or procedure or function) associated with a class." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)

Comment: Since they are the same, what exactly are you suggesting I do?

Comment: they are not the same. methods are function defined in the scope of classes and it instances.

Comment: Where should I define the function if I want it to be global, then?

Comment: how about altering your initial question, that also people see it, that do not work themselves through all comments?

Comment: To try and help with the method/function confusion a bit more--it's sort of like how when you're a kid, you learn that all squares are rectangles, but not all rectangles are squares.  All methods are functions--they're blocks of code that can be called and executed by name. But methods are special types of functions that are part of a class :)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility: You can define a category on an `UIViewController` with the method. So any `UIViewController` now has this method too.

Another possibility: subclass a `UIViewController` and write you method there. And then subclass from this custom viewcontroller.

Edit:

> Also, my MasterViewController is a subclass of the UITableViewController while the DetailViewController is a subclass of UIViewController. If I subclass them both to a custom UIViewController, the MasterViewController will lose its UITableViewController inheritance

You could subclass a `UITableViewController` and do the same thing as with the `UIViewController` and subclass from this.

The basic idea is to have a `UITableViewController` and a `UIViewController` as template.

Comment: The problem with these approaches is that, since my globally accessible methods must connect to a web server, they must share an NSInputStream and NSOutputStream. Categories don't support variables/properties. Also, my MasterViewController is a subclass of the UITableViewController while the DetailViewController is a subclass of UIViewController. If I subclass them both to a custom UIViewController, the MasterViewController will lose its UITableViewController inheritance.

Comment: edited my answer. And in your original question there was (and still is!) just a mention to a global method - nothing about variables. So edit you question for more detail please.

Answer (score 2):

You can create methods in the appDelegate class that you can access through all your app.  For example, in your AppDelegate.h you have declared this method as follow:

```
-(void)myMethod;
```

In your AppDelegate.m, you define it as:

```
-(void)myMethod
{
    NSLog(@"myMethod is getting called");
}
```

From any other classes (Master or Detail, etc.), you access myMethod by:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate myMethod];
```

Answer (score 1):

make the class and the methods static. use the plus instead of minus e.g. `+(void)methodName:param(ParamType *);` .

Note, you can't instantiate a object of this class. It is like procedural programming. I usually use if I need the same but changing value in different objects and views. I don't a better way it works for me, though.

Comment: Yes, this seems like a good idea, but it is essentially what hotpaw2 said.